# The equation has the same variable twice but only one of it is updated (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

A newbie here!

So the problem is: there's a farmer, who initially has 1 cow, which produces 3 liters of milk per day, and 1 liter of milk costs $3. Once the farmer's income is more than $300, he can buy another cow that will also produce milk for him (a cow costs $300) and this process goes on and on. So I need to know how many cows the farmer will have after a number of days.
I wrote this code, but the "income" variable doesn't update after a new cow "is bought".
Thank you for your help and dedicated time!

```
const cowPrice = 300;
const milkPrice = 3;
const milkLitersPerDay = 3;
var cowsNumber = 1;
var daysPassed = 45;

for (var i = 0; i <= daysPassed; i++) {
    var income = (i * milkLitersPerDay * milkPrice * cowsNumber)-((cowsNumber-1) * cowPrice);
    console.log(income);
    if (income >= 300) {
        cowsNumber++;
        console.log(cowsNumber);
    }
}
```

Here is the executed code, the income doesn't get nullified after it goes beyond 300:
[image: Here is the executed code, the income doesn't get nullified after it goes beyond 300]

Comment: you need `-300` from `income` because a new cow costs 300. in your code, you need to write `income -= 300` in `if (income >= 300) { .. }`.

Comment: your math is also wrong. it should like this `income += milkLitersPerDay * cowsNumber * milkPrice;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
const cowPrice = 300;
const milkPrice = 3;
let milkLitersPerDay = 3;
let cowsNumber = 1;
let daysPassed = 45;
let income = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= daysPassed; i++) {
    income += (milkLitersPerDay * cowsNumber) * milkPrice;
    console.log("income:", income, "day:", i);
    if (income >= 300) {
        income -= 300;
        cowsNumber++;
        console.log("cow:", cowsNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but your code doesn't take into account the period when the farmer's daily income is more than $600 and he can buy 2+ cows per day, for example

Comment: I improved your code a little bit:

Comment: @Osmancho you're right. you can stack more conditions on top of `if (income >= 300)` like `if (income >= 900) { ... } else if (income >= 600) { ... } else ...`. even better you can use `switch case` to check conditions. tip: always stack the higher amount on top of lower amount. that way it's more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const cowPrice = 300;
    const milkPrice = 3;
    const milkLitersPerDay = 3;
    let cowsNumber = 1;
    let daysPassed = 120;
    let income = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i <= daysPassed; i++) {
        income += milkLitersPerDay * cowsNumber * milkPrice;

        for (let k = 1; k < daysPassed; k++) {
            if (income >= 300 * k && income < 300 * (k + 1)) {
                income -= 300 * k;
                cowsNumber += 1 * k;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("After", daysPassed, "days");
    console.log("the farmer owns", cowsNumber, "cows");
    console.log("and his remaining income is $", income + ".");
    console.log(
        "At that moment he gets",
        milkLitersPerDay * cowsNumber,
        "liters of milk per day"
    );
    console.log(
        "and earns $",
        milkLitersPerDay * cowsNumber * milkPrice,
        "per day."
    );
    console.log(
        "His total revenue is $",
        milkLitersPerDay * cowsNumber * milkPrice * daysPassed
    );
```